# Unable to add button click event in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add `dialog` on button click inside `jqGrid` but receiving `"Uncaught ReferenceError: OpenDialog is not defined"` error. I think I've used all needed references but no luck.

Also, If I use the same code in `jsFiddle` then neither get any error nor expected result.

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjan_prmr/2pxsshg9/)

I tried using `id: "QueryLink"` in function as well but no luck.

What am I missing here?

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  function OpenDialog() {
  alert("1");
    $("#myDialogBox").dialog("open");
  }

  $("#grid1").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
      {
        name: "QueryLink",
        id: "QueryLink",
        label: "Query Link",
        align: "center",
        formatter: function() {
          return "<button onclick='OpenDialog()'>Pop Up</button>";
        }
      }
    ],
    data: [{
      QueryLink: "Link"
    }],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "invdate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Button Click Test"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>

<table id="grid1"></table>
<div id="myDialogBox" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that you're including jQueryUI before jQuery, and also multiple versions of jQuery and jqGrid which is causing errors in the code. You need to organise the included scripts correctly.

The issue itself is because you're using an `on*` event attribute. This means that the function you call must be declared under the scope of the `window`, so you need to move `OpenDialog()` outside of the `$(function() {});` block.

You also need to call `dialog()` on the `#myDialogBox` div to intantiate the library on that element. Presumably you want to se `autoOpen: false` so that it only opens when you manually trigger it. Try this:

```js
function OpenDialog() {
  alert("1");
  $("#myDialogBox").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  $("#myDialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });

  $("#grid1").jqGrid({
    colModel: [{
      name: "QueryLink",
      id: "QueryLink",
      label: "Query Link",
      align: "center",
      formatter: function() {
        return "<button onclick='OpenDialog()'>Pop Up</button>";
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      QueryLink: "Link"
    }],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "invdate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Button Click Test"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="grid1"></table>
<div id="myDialogBox" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

However a better solution would be to remove the outdated `onclick` attribute and use a delegated event handler instead, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  $("#myDialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  
  $("#grid1").jqGrid({
    colModel: [{
      name: "QueryLink",
      id: "QueryLink",
      label: "Query Link",
      align: "center",
      formatter: function() {
        return '<button class="popup-trigger">Pop Up</button>';
      }
    }],
    data: [{
      QueryLink: "Link"
    }],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "invdate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "Button Click Test"
  }).on('click', '.popup-trigger', function() {
    alert("1");
    $("#myDialogBox").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="grid1"></table>
<div id="myDialogBox" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

Comment: This is very helpful info. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @CSharper: Small additional advice: please use always the same version of CSS and JS files (you use JS from 4.14.0 and JS from 4.13.6 version). By the way, the last released version of free jqGrid ise 4.14.1, which I'd recommend you to use.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, This is the bigger picture. I am trying to incorporate pop-up logic in this grid, [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gunjan_prmr/8cL9tscy/3/). If I use `function()` and follow your logic it works fine but in my grid, it is little different. Any suggestions?

Comment: My first thought is that you have several script errors in the console. I'd suggest starting with fixing those.